# Regex.Replace and String.Replace does not work

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string `01-Jan-2014 00:00:00` and I intend to shorten the year into 2 characters.

my code:

```
DateTime dtParsedDate = new DateTime();
string strInput = "01-Jan-2014 00:00:00";
Regex regDate = new Regex(@"\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}");

// parse into datetime object
dtParsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(regDate.Match(strInput).Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// replace the string with new format
regDate.Replace(arrData[iCol], dtParsedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"));
```

I've verified that the string is matched correctly using regex.

"01-Jan-2014" did not get replaced into "01-Jan-14". What is wrong with my code?

Comment: [Read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx). `Regex.Replace` returns a new string, it does not mutate the string you pass in to it (because strings are immutable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` and `String.Replace` do not modify the existing string: they return the modified string. Try changing your code to:

```
arrData[iCol] = regDate.Replace(arrData[iCol], dtParsedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET strings are immutable and all replace methods do not replace in-place but return a new string with the replacements done.